# Data on 'Firebase Realtime Database' is not updating from my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning Firebase Realtime Database (with Flutter). I'm facing a problem which is that when I send data from my app to Firebase Realtime Dattabase, it is not updating.

I'm entering the project file code below. You may check the complete project on the GitHub Repo (https://github.com/Aabis-Ahmed-Hassan/Firebase-Practice).

**Code**

```
      import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
      import 'package:firebase_practice/widgets/my_round_button.dart';
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
      
      import '../utils/utils.dart';
      
      class AddPost extends StatefulWidget {
        const AddPost({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      
        @override
        State<AddPost> createState() => _AddPostState();
      }
      
      class _AddPostState extends State<AddPost> {
        final postController = TextEditingController();
        bool loading = false;
        final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Post');
      
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Add Post'),
            ),
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    maxLines: 4,
                    controller: postController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'What is in your mind?',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  MyRoundButton(
                      title: 'Add',
                      loading: loading,
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          loading = true;
                        });
      
                        String id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
                        databaseRef.child(id).set({
                          'title': postController.text.toString(),
                          // 'id': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()
                        }).then((value) {
                          Utils().showToastMessage('Post added');
                          setState(() {
                            loading = false;
                          });
                        }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
                          Utils().showToastMessage(error.toString());
                          setState(() {
                            loading = false;
                          });
                        });
                      })
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
```

**I want to mention two things.**

1. In the same flutter project, Firebase Authentication (signup, login) was working perfectly.
2. Maybe there is any configuration error so I'm attaching the link of the GitHub Repo link of the project which is https://github.com/Aabis-Ahmed-Hassan/Firebase-Practice

**Project File Code:**

[Project Code Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw2fs.png)

[Project Code Image 2 (Where I've hit Firebase)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JanQ.png)

**Dependencies**

[Pubspec.yaml File Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3wTt.png)

**Firebase**

[Firebase Console is not updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiMAq.png)

[Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp49b.png)

Thanks

Previously, in the rules tap of Firebase Realtime Database, some digits were written in front of read and write (probably like ".read" :n<2323) but now, I've changed them to true. The data is not updating in either of the situations.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

From checking the [`firebase_options.dart` file](https://github.com/Aabis-Ahmed-Hassan/Firebase-Practice/blob/main/lib/firebase_options.dart) in the GitHub link you shared, your configuration does not include a `databaseURL` value. Most likely this means that you created the configuration before you created the database in the Firebase console.

The two most common options to fix this are:

- Rerun `flutterfire configure` to update the configuration in `firebase_options.dart`.
- Specify the database URL in your code.

The first option is probably best here.